# How can I determine which add-ins are causing the biggest performance issues for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 has gone from snappy to slow. It has gone from idling at 0% CPU usage to idling at 25% CPU usage. It has gone from taking about half a gig of RAM for a loaded project, taking over 1GB of RAM for that same project.

The longer I leave Visual Studio 2010 open, the worse the performance.

I know the culprit must be an add-in, but I can't seem to figure out which one. I am using Process Explorer to examine the process.

---

EDIT: My current add-ins and extensions:  .Net Reflector, Gallio, Visual Git, AnkhSVN, Git Source Control Provider, Iron Python Tools for Visual Studio, MonoDroid for Visual Studio, NuGet Package Manager, Power Commands for Visual Studio 2010, Productivity Power Tools, Visual Studio Color Theme Editor

(a screen like Chrome's that will tell you which tab is using up the processor would be ideal!)

Comment: Do You have pro-power tools pack installed? What other add-ins do you have, majorly?

Comment: Edited my post with the list of what I have installed.

Comment: Productivity Power Tools has been notorious for perf problems.

Comment: Can you try running the diagnostics tool that i mentioned in this post, and log a bug @ connect.microsoft.com. We would be interested to see if Pro-power tools affecting your Perf. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to measure the perf for each add-in. But a tool that could be handy is 
[VS Diagnostics Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e8649e35-26b1-4e73-b427-c2886a0705f4). You can install this tool, and when you see your performance is degrading, during some scenarios, you can record the ETLs traces and Log a bug [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/) with relevant traces. The Visual Studio team can look at the traces and provide you suggestions based on that.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio PerfWatson](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fa85b17d-3df2-49b1-bee6-71527ffef441?SRC=Home) seems to be a better / easier way to track and report performance issues with Visual Studio 2010 Sp1

(from the article):

> Here’s how it works: when the tool
>   detects that the Visual Studio UI has
>   become unresponsive, it records
>   information about the length of the
>   delay and the root cause, and submits
>   a report to Microsoft. The Visual
>   Studio team can then aggregate the
>   data from these reports to prioritize
>   the issues that are causing the
>   largest or most frequent delays across
>   our user base. By installing the
>   PerfWatson extension, you are helping
>   Microsoft identify and fix the
>   performance issues that you most
>   frequently encounter on your PC.

Comment: Except when the PerfWatson process itself causes your performance issues.